# Android Navigation Drawer Layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-design-library, navigationview

**In Landscape Mode I want to create navigation drawer which is placed at the bottom left of screen and the drawer opens from bottom to top .......Is this possible to create...........??**

*I have uploaded the picture below according to which I want to create navigation drawer in landscape*

[image: Custom navigation Drawer Is this possible to create???]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible to create...........??

Yes possible.

**I will tell you how you can achieve this.**

1. You have to have two layout for portrait and landscape layout.
2. For portrait view you can user navigation drawer as simple as that
3. For landscape you can use the  `BottomSheet` from support library that you can swipe up and down like navigation drawer & on click of button of hamburger you can open bottom sheet

See example for **[BottomSheet](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)**

Comment: Can u explain me in detail N J actually I have to make it fixed to landscape not in portrait so forget about portrait I just want to use it in landscape mode only

Comment: Added link to example

Comment: Ok Thanxxx N J also can I rotate that bottom sheet as if it looks like used in portrait but actually in landscape mode

Comment: @Prashant Gald to help you. Please accept & vote up the answer :) , As it indicates helpful

Comment: I have voted for U @N J please answer my last question too about the rotation of bottom sheet to look alike portrait mode in landscape

Comment: @Prashant you accepted answer you can vote-up as well. The arrow above the answer :) for vote up